# Buefy - Dynamically load fields in table with customization

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I'm using the code below to load a table, which works well. However the fields of the dataset can vary, so I would like the template for the table to be dynamic.

So instead of defining each column in code, I would like it to load as many columns as are in the data, using the provided template. To do this, I need to replace {{props.row.uid}} by something similar where the "uid" part is dynamically loaded with the value from "column.field".

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this...

```
<template>
    <b-table :data="data">
    <template v-for="column in columns">
        <b-table-column :key="column" :field="column.field" :label="column.label" centered v-slot="props">
            <template v-if="column.type === 'string'">
                <span>{{props.row.uid}}</span>
            </template>
            <template v-if="column.type === 'list'">
                <span v-for="item in props.row.list" :key="item" class="tag mr-2">{{item}}</span>
            </template>
        </b-table-column>
    </template>
    </b-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [
                    { 'uid': 1, 'list': ["Value1","Value2","Value3"] },
                    { 'uid': 2, 'list': ["Value1","Value2","Value3"] },
                    { 'uid': 3, 'list': ["Value1","Value2","Value3"] }
                ],
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'uid',
                        label: 'UID',
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'list',
                        label: 'List',
                        type: 'list'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't try this sooner, but following did the job:

```
props.row[column.field]
```